# How can I target status bar color or opacity in a Flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I couldn't find an attribute in the Scaffold or AppBar classes to do this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can change the text color of the status bar from light to dark using [`SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setSystemUIOverlayStyle.html). For example, to make the status bar font black:

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark);
```

However, the [`AppBar`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html) widget also calls `setSystemUIOverlayStyle` in its build function and may interfere with you. If you're building an app that uses `AppBar` widget, you should probably set the `brightness` on your `AppBar` to be Brightness.dark (if you want a light text status bar) or Brightness.light (if you want a dark text status bar).

To hide the status indicator entirely, use [`SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setEnabledSystemUIOverlays.html).

I'm not sure if Flutter has an API for customize the text opacity or background color. There isn't a background at all on iOS, but you could draw one yourself.

Comment: I am using `AppBar` in my app and have set `brightness: Brightness.light` and still the status bar icon color (Android) is white.

Answer (score 1):

```
  // set status bar color with opacity
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
      statusBarColor: Color(0x22CACACA)
  ));
```

1. You can set status bar color(`CACACA` part after `0x22`).
2. You can set color opacity(`22` part after `0x`).